# iOS - AVPlayer not streaming audio for some URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, buffer, avplayer

I have tried play audio from streaming. It is working fine with some URL but for some with some URL (http://listen.radionomy.com/almightyradiohindi) it fails even player status comes = AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay.  If I put same URL which is not working in browser then there it also does not work. But I think player should not show status as = AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay. I am facing problem to manage it. For example how to I know for which streaming URL AVPlayer will work or not ?

My code :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
    AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem];
    [avPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (object == avPlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {

        if (avPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"\n\n **** AVPlayer Failed  ***\n\n");
        }

        else if (avPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            NSLog(@"\n\n ****  AVPlayer Ready to Play   ****\n\n");
            [avPlayer play];

        }
        else if (avPlayer.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"\n\n  **** AVPlayer Unknown  \n\n ****");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NSURL *streamingURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL_STRING];
    NSLog(@"%@", streamingURL);
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:streamingURL];
    [player play];

Comment: Have you figured out the issue?

Comment: @Ravi Have u got any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

when I open your audio url(http://listen.radionomy.com/almightyradiohindi) in browser it will change to (http://streaming.radionomy.com/AlmightyRadioHindi?lang=en-US%2cen%3bq%3d0.8%2cfa%3bq%3d0.6)
if you can get the exact url and url-encode it the problem will be fixed

url encoding in swift 3.0:

```
var originalString = "test/test"
var escapedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
print(escapedString!)
```

Comment: @ Hamid, changed URL also not playing in Browser . So no need to encode/decode here.